# Custom View getHitRect return wrong value

Tags: android

I created a new custom view that looks like this

```
public class SearchCategoryPanel extends RelativeLayout {

    private boolean hasRetrieved = false;

    private GridLayout categoryContainer;

    private TextView scpLoadingText;

    public static final int HEIGHT = 360;

    private ArrayList<OnCategoryItemClickListener> onCategoryItemClickListeners = new ArrayList<OnCategoryItemClickListener>();

    public SearchCategoryPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public SearchCategoryPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.i(SearchCategoryPanel.class.getSimpleName(), this.getTop() + "");
        init();
    }

    public SearchCategoryPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.search_category_panel, this);
        this.scpLoadingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sCategoryPanelLoadingText);
        this.categoryContainer = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.sCategoryContainer);
        this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void show() {
        this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hide() {
        this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void setProcessing(boolean on) {
        if(!on) {
            this.scpLoadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            this.scpLoadingText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void addCategoryItemUsingVo(CategoryVo categoryVo) {
        CategoryItem item = new CategoryItem(getContext());
        item.setCategoryVo(categoryVo);
        item.setOnItemClickListener(new CategoryItem.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(CategoryVo categoryVo) {
                triggerOnCategoryItemClickListener(categoryVo);
            }
        });
        this.categoryContainer.addView(item);
    }

    public void removeAllItems() {
        this.categoryContainer.removeAllViews();
    }

    public boolean hasRetrieved() {
        return hasRetrieved;
    }

    public interface OnCategoryItemClickListener {
        public void onClick(CategoryVo categoryVo);
    }

    public void setOnCategoryItemClickListener(OnCategoryItemClickListener listener) {
        this.onCategoryItemClickListeners.add(listener);
    }

    private void triggerOnCategoryItemClickListener(CategoryVo vo) {
        for(OnCategoryItemClickListener listener : onCategoryItemClickListeners ) {
            listener.onClick(vo);
        }
    }


}
```

Then, I try to call the getHitRect

```
 Rect rectF = new Rect();
                searchCategoryPanel.getHitRect(rectF);
                Log.i(ARModeActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Rect: " + rectF.toString());
```

The log returns strange value: Rect: Rect(0, 0 - 1920, 1164). this means the relative layout covers the whole screen which is not correct.

The SearchCategoryPanel xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#7F000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:maxHeight="360dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search Category"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sCategoryPanelLoadingText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Loading.."/>


        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/sCategoryContainer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </GridLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The relative layout only has 360dp in height, andfull width (look at the xml). but it returns the wrong value. I have read about onMeasure and onSizeChanged, but nothing helped

Here How I call the search_category_panel layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootArMode"
    tools:context="com.imav.ARModeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlInfoARMode"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#7F000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="Interaction Guide"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Select: "/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Tap on object with 1 finger "/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Move: "/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Touch and Drag Object with 1 finger "/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Rotate: "/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Touch and drag object with 2 fingers "/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Scale: "/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Touch and pinch object with 2 fingers "/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCloseArMode"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"

        android:background="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlOpenActionBar"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOpenActionBar"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_backspace_white_24dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/rlActionBar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#7F000000"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnInfoArMode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_error_white_24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAddObjArMode"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSaveSceneArMode" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSaveSceneArMode"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_white_24dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/pbSaveSceneArMode"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnShareARMode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTrashArMode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.imav.view.SearchCataloguePanel
        android:id="@+id/searchCataloguePanelArMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.imav.view.SearchCataloguePanel>

    <com.imav.view.SearchCategoryPanel
        android:id="@+id/searchCategoryPanelArMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </com.imav.view.SearchCategoryPanel>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first approach would be not to override the `onMeasure()` in your custom view `SearchCategoryPanel`. Because you are forcing a different dimension than the ones provided by the `xml`.

Comment: If i remove the onMeasure, the result will still the same

Comment: i have removed the onmeasure

Comment: Can you post the xml where you are using the `SearchCategoryPanel` ?

Comment: That does not help. Please post the xml file were you are using the `SearchCategoryPanel`.

Comment: I don't see anything that might be causing this. Can you post a screenshot of the the UI?

Comment: so it is not because of the custom view? do you see the rlactionbar, the rlactionbar is correct, while the custom view searchcategorypanel and searchcataloguepanel are wrong. i need to ask my boss for this. let me get back to you